# Using sympy to solve equations, why the result contains unknowns sometimes

Tags: python

My python code:

```py
def Kinematic_turn(L, M, N, p, q, r):
    Ix = 9496
    Iy = 55814
    Iz = 63100
    Ixy = 0
    Iyz = 0
    Izx = 982
    x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z')
    eq = [Ix * x + (Iz - Iy) * q * r + Iyz * (r ** 2 - q ** 2) + Ixy * (
                r * p - y) - Izx * (p * q + z) - L,
          Iy * y + (Ix - Iz) * p * r + Izx * (p ** 2 - r ** 2) + Iyz * (
                      p * q - z) - Ixy * (q * r + x) - M,
          Iz * z + (Iy - Ix) * p * q + Ixy * (q ** 2 - p ** 2) + Izx * (
                      q * r - x) - Iyz * (r * p + y) - N]
    result = linsolve(eq, [x, y, z])
    print(result)
    (p_dot, q_dot, r_dot) = next(iter(result))
    return p_dot, q_dot, r_dot

p_dot, q_dot, r_dot = Kinematic_turn(10e-9, -45989, 10, 0, 0, 0)
```

Result:

```py
FiniteSet((53161723108149.8 - 3.34910612568497e+17*z, -0.823968896692586, 1.0*z))
```

Why there is `z` in the result?

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes that there is a unique solution to your system, or at least that only the first expression is the only one you are interested in. Indeed, you write:

```
(p_dot, q_dot, r_dot) = next(iter(result))
return p_dot, q_dot, r_dot
```

which means that only the first tuple of expressions from `result` will be returned (and you don't check whether it is the only one)

It seems here that your system has actually infinitely many solutions, including a straight line t→(x,y,z)=(at-b,c,t).

Nota: To understand how linear systems and `linsolve` work, try this:
`linsolve([x+y-1,2*(x+y-1)],[x,y])`
where obviously the set of equations is not free.

Comment: I worked out the same equations by hand, and there's a unique solution.

Comment: You are right, because of the data type, the equation is linearly correlated. When I change 1e-8 into 0, there's a unique solution.

Comment: Remember to accept answer if it's solving issue, @littlefirewooder